# Accessing external database from within GCP Cloud Run container

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Is it possible to access an arbitrary Oracle database from within the python code used in a Google Cloud Run container?
Could Integration Services be used for that?  Is e.g. possible to access a DB integration service programatically from python code?

Comment: Many questions for only one questions. Yes, you can access Oracle Database from python script, as long as you have all the component installed on your container. a 4 yo article on that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/reach-oracle-db-in-serverless-271293f79861 About Cloud Integration Service, can you share more on it, which service, which context?

Comment: Rephrasing the Q...  if I wanted to develop a service on a VM I'd simply use the cx_oracle library and connect to a remote Oracle DB from a python code.
Before I start experimenting with Cloud Run I wanted to understand what is possible in principle. 
What I already got is that Cloud Run does not allow direct TCP comms to any external resources and GCP provides Integration Connectors which act as middle components. But I'm not able to figure out how such Connectors could be used from python code executed in a CR container... which may mean I'm on a completely wrong track...

Comment: Did you read my article? Using Cloud Run and a VM is no really different. What's your blokcers?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - many thanks for the pointer to your article. I see your point but to me the message there w.r.t. Cloud Run is rather inconclusive... the original version says it was not possible but then it adds a pointer to the VPC egress  feature release saying it should be possible now. 
What I meant by a VM in my original Q as a reference is any arbitrary VM in my network, not a GCP VM.